# Looking for mass cropping software

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, image-processing

I'm looking for a tool than runs on Ubuntu that can let me:

- Open an image in a folder which has thousands
- Crop and rotate it
- Save as a copy, automatically named (not manually), with one click. Preferably with something in the name that I can later use to filter these cropped copies in Nautilus (unless it saves in another directory, that'd be even better).
- Move to next image and repeat

Does it exist?

Comment: Is the crop always to the same size (or same ratio of the initial image), or does the user need to tell the tool how to crop each image? Is the area to keep always the centre of the image or does it vary from image to image? Is the rotation always in the same direction by the same amount?

Comment: @Blair No, the images are "raw" photos that I need to crop and rotate manually and differently for every image.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) which comes pre-instaled with Ubuntu! :)

`convert -rotate 90 *.jpg`

Read the on the [website](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) on how to crop (using the -crop parameter), which will vary depending on how much you want to crop and where to crop.

Comment: I don't think that'll be very comfortable. I need to see the images first, otherwise I wouldn't know how to rotate and crop. All in all it's not very speedy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried digikam?  That's really it but I have to have thirty characters to post.  So, try digikam.  It's in the USC.

Comment: +1 for digikam, if you do not need all the features it has you can also try showFoto for image editing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this doesn't address all your steps, and does not launch any GUI interaction at all, but I find the need to auto-crop a lot in the course of my nightly batch processing, after many screenshots and browser or application snapshots were generated.

Here's my use of `convert`(from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) bundle already mentioned):

```
# find all PNGs in imgdir/ younger than a day
for f in $(find imgdir/ -mtime -1 -name \*.png); do  

# trim off edges of unchanging color and reduce to 6-bit color depth
convert -trim +repage -colors 64 -depth 6 -verbose $f $f.trimmed.png;   

# shrink the PNG file size with aggressive optimize
optipng -keep -preserve -o6 -v   $f.trimmed.png

ls -lFa $f*
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the image magick tools with find and okdir, previously invoking "disply" to have a look at it:

```
find -name "*.jpg" -exec display {} ";" -okdir convert -rotate 90 {} {}.rotated.jpg ";"
```

It renames the result from kitten.jpg to kitten.jpg.rotated.jpg. If you want to remove the inner '.jpg', it would be more easy later in one go with the `rename` tool (from the perl package):

```
rename 's/.jpg.rotate/.rotate/' *.jpg.rotate.jpg
```

For rotating, I would use eog (Eye of Gnome) where you have different views on the images, and can easily rotate left/right/180°, and save. But afaik, it doesn't has cropping.

Image Magick has a GUI interface too, but I don't remember its name, and can't say if it is useful for cropping, if you have different dimensions per image to crop to.